# QuickBlox custom objects permission

Tags: quickblox

I'm having some trouble setting permission in quickblox custom objet.

Lets say I have 2 users: `userA` and `userB`, they can create object and, by default,
every user can see only it's objects.
I want `userB` can access (read) an object of userA so I 
set the read permission on the `userA`'s object this way:

```
?permissions[read][access]=open_for_users_ids&permissions[read][ids]=<userBid>
```

the operation seems to success, when I check on the web interface I can see the object with the right permissions but still userB can't access that `userA`'s object!!

If I update the object from the web (without changing anything, just press the update button),
`userB` can see userA's object.

I followed this [documentation](http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects#Update_record_with_permissions)

What's wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'every user can see only it's objects'.

By default, every user can request all objects, not only his own

Comment: You are right, but when I create an object I set the permission like this:  ?permissions[read][access]=owner